# How to create a matrix out of different matrices with different number of rows in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a for loop in matlab, in which I want to make a matrix out of different matrices with different number of rows( I don't know what the difference of number of rows is gonna be). For example I have two matrices that are 10x1, and 4x1. How can I make a matrix from both of them.(In this case I know what is the difference, but in my loop I won't know their differences.)

```
A =

    0.1000
    0.5000
    0.6000
    0.8000
    0.3000
    0.2000
    0.7000
    0.6000
    0.1000
    1.0000

B =

    0.1000
    0.2000
    0.3000
    0.4000

C =

    0.1000    0.1000
    0.5000    0.2000
    0.6000    0.3000
    0.8000    0.4000
    0.3000       NaN
    0.2000       NaN
    0.7000       NaN
    0.6000       NaN
    0.1000       NaN
    1.0000       NaN
```

I want my last matrix to be like C.

Comment: If your 10x1 matrix is `A`, and your 4x1 matrix is `B`, then you can do `M=[A;B]`. If you want to add another Nx1 matrix `C`, do `M=[M;C]`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what I want is the combination of A and B as a 10 by 2 column matrix that have zero or NAN for missing rows in matrix B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Double Arrays

You can create matrices in MATLAB from concatenating other matrices together as long as the result is rectangular.
So, per your example, a new matrix/vector can be made by doing the following since the concatenation results in a rectangular output:

```
u   = rand(10,1);
v   = rand(4,1);
newVector = [u;v];
```

However, you cannot simply concatenate `u` and `v` into different columns since their row count differ.
So, a fill of some sort is necessary to balance the number of rows:

```
newMatrix = [ u , [v ; zeros(length(u)-length(v),1)]];
```

where the non-existent rows of `v` have been filled by a vector of `0`s.
If you want a NaN fill, simply multiply the zero vector by `NaN`.
If you don't know whether `u` or `v` has greater length, you can do the following:

```
maxRows   = max([length(u),length(v)]);
nFillRows = abs(length(u) - length(v));

%   The fill vector will be empty if the vector has the maximum number of rows
uColumn   = [u ; zeros( nFillRows * (length(u) ~= maxRows) ,1)];
vColumn   = [v ; zeros( nFillRows * (length(v) ~= maxRows) ,1)];

newMatrix = [uColumn,vColumn];
```

In order for this to work, the number of rows to add needs to be known.
This can be set up recursively to make `newMatrix` larger and larger (though `size()` may need to be used if either `u` or `v` is a matrix instead of a vector); however, dynamically growing arrays can be a big performance hit.

## Cell Arrays

If the for-loop's purpose is to generate a list of vectors that you simply want to store and use later, a cell array may be a good data structure to use:

```
vectorStorage = {u,v};
```

Since each element of a cell array can have it's own separate data type, it doesn't matter that `u` and `v` have different lengths.
From the command line, you will see this:

```
>> vectorStorage = {u,v}

vectorStorage = 

    [10x1 double]    [4x1 double]
```

The first element is vector `u`, and the second element is vector `v`.
You can recall the value stored by specifying the index in curly braces: `all(u == vectorStorage{1}) == 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your first vector is `A`, create `M` by `M=A`, then for each new vector you wish to add, you can use this code:

```
if length(B)>size(M,1)
    M=[M;nan(length(B)-size(M,1),size(M,2))];
    M=[M B];
else
    M=[M [B;nan(size(M,1)-length(B),1)]];
end
```

Although Troy's suggestion of using a cell array is a good idea for such a situation.